# Dynamically access object property by using "$this"

Tags: php, zend-db, zend-framework3, php-7.2, tablegateway

I have next lines in my code to get the entity in ZF3:

```
$entity = $this->userCredentialsTableGateway
               ->getResultSetPrototype()
               ->getArrayObjectPrototype();
```

To automate it for different tables I created a function:

```
private function getEntityFromGateway( $table )
{
    $context = $table . "TableGateway";
    return $this->$context
                ->getResultSetPrototype()
                ->getArrayObjectPrototype();
}
```

When I try to get

```
$entity = $this->getEntityFromTableGateway( "UserCredentials" )
```

it gives an error:

```
Undefined property: 
User\DataGateway\UserDataGateway::$UserCredentialsTableGateway
```

So, some why `$this->$var` acts like `$this->$$var`.
PHP version 7.2

Comment: It's case sensitive, so UserCredentials wouldn't be the same as userCredentials.

Comment: `$context = lcfirst($table) . "TableGateway"; ` .. works, but it isn't beautiful

Comment: Oh no... it was silly misspelling. The problem was not in $this context. My bad. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do slight modification on your existing code.

1. Wrap variable and string with curly braces like this `"{$table}TableGateway"`
2. Lower case table name's first character only e.g if you've all table at first later small case use instead it like this `$context = lcfirst("{$table}TableGateway")`

So your code will be like this

```
private function getEntityFromGateway( $table )
{
    $context = lcfirst("{$table}TableGateway");
    return $this->$context
                ->getResultSetPrototype()
                ->getArrayObjectPrototype();
}
```

and call it like this way as you're already doing,

```
$entity = $this->getEntityFromTableGateway( "UserCredentials" )
```

Comment: OMG! I can't believe that I've just misspelled the variable name! You are right - the first letter must be "lowercased". I didn't use PHP for some time so I decided that there are must be some rules with "$this" that I've forgot.. but it was silly misspelling.. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @kereell, glad it helps you somehow. Best of luck :)